# How to find volume of solid using double integrals?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Trying to find the volume of the solid bounded by the parabolic cylinders $z=7x^2, y=x^2$ and the planes $z=0, y=4$.

I'm not sure how to set up the range of outer integral. Here's what I have so far: $$ \int \int_{x^2}^4 7x^2 \ dy \ dx $$

Comment: Are you sure what you describe is a cylinder? I cannot see how it is

Comment: @user160738 The solid is not a cylinder but it is bounded by two cylinders and two planes.

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what solid you are referring to, because $z=7x^2$, $y=x^2$ only describes a parabolic curve, so solid bounded by this curve and $z=0,y=4$ does not exist. But I suspect the one you are considering has volume $14\left(8-\frac{16}{3}\right)$

Comment: @user160738 They are parabolic cylinders, I will edit to clarify. Also that is not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this picture the vertical axis is $z$, the arrow pointing down is $y$, and the arrow pointing left is $x$.
[image: ![enter image description here]

> Trying to find the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinders $z=7x^2, y=x^2$ and the planes $z=0, y=4$.

Starting from $x^2 ≤y≤ 4$, you need to then bound $z$ and $x$. $z$ is constrained by the parabolic cylinder $z=7x^2≥0$ and $z=0$ so we want $0≤z≤7x^2$.
Finally we are then free to use the maximal and minimal values of $x$. As $y≤4$ and $y=x^2$ is the constraint that affects $x$, we see that $-2≤x≤2$. [Putting this together,](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triple%20integral&a=*MC.~-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=1&f=TripleIntegral.integrand_1&f3=y&f=TripleIntegral.intvariable1i_y&f4=x%5E2&f=TripleIntegral.rangestart1i_x%5E2&f5=4&f=TripleIntegral.rangeend1i_4&f6=z&f=TripleIntegral.intvariable2m_z&f7=0&f=TripleIntegral.rangestart2m%5Cu005f0&f8=7x%5E2&f=TripleIntegral.rangeend2m_7x%5E2&f9=x&f=TripleIntegral.intvariable3_x&f10=-2&f=TripleIntegral.rangestart3_-2&f11=2&f=TripleIntegral.rangeend3_2)

$$ V = ∫_{x=-2}^2 ∫_{z=0}^{7x^2} ∫_{y=x^2}^4 \ dy \ dz \ dx = \frac{896}{15}$$